# Printing an unordered list that is in a ordered list by using a for each loop in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, list, foreach, thymeleaf

I'm working on a project that needs me to print a unorded list in a orded list.

The code that i currently have only displays the firt list item like the following:

1. Surname name
2. Surname name
   etc....

The tags getThemePark aren't empty but won't display for some odd reason.

```
<ol>
    <th:block th:each="v : ${visitors}">
    <li th:text = "${v.getSurName()} + ' '+ ${v.getFirstName()}" th:with ="" >
        <ul>
            <li th:text = "${v} + ' '+ ${v.getThemeParkCode()} "></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </th:block>
</ol>
```

This is the code that makes sure i can use visitors in thymeleaf html

```
@RequestMapping("/6_ShowAllVisitors")
    public String DisplayVisitors(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("visitors", visitors);
        return "/6_ShowAllVisitors";
    }
    enter code here
```

My arrays are build like this if it helps.

```
private ArrayList<Visitor> fillVisitors() {
Visitor visitor4 = new Visitor("Name", "Surname");
        visitor4.setYearOfBirth(int year);
        visitors.add(visitor4);
        visitors.get(3).addToWishList("nameOfAttraction");
        visitors.get(3).addToWishList("nameOfAttraction");
...
```

This is how I start my MainController.Java

```
    private ArrayList<Visitor> visitors;


    @PostConstruct
    private void fillData() {
        visitors = new ArrayList<>(fillVisitors());
    }
```

More information about the Visitors class:

```
public class Visitor extends Person{
  private int yearOfBirth;
  private int themeParkCode;
  


    public Visitor(String firstName, String surName) {
        super(firstName, surName);
        wishList = new ArrayList<>();
        themeParkCode = -1;
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int getYearOfBirth() {
        return yearOfBirth;
    }

    public void setYearOfBirth(int yearOfBirth) {
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    }

    public int getThemeParkCode() {
        return themeParkCode;
    }

    public void setThemeParkCode(int themeParkCode) {
        this.themeParkCode = themeParkCode;
    }
```

This is the parent class op Visitor:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;

    public Person(){}

    public Person(String firstName, String surName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }

    public void setSurName(String surName) {
        this.surName = surName;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add more detail of your `Visitor` class?

Comment: @msucil Just added a bunch of my code, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `th:text` overwrites anything inside of the tag it appears in.  The contents of your template should probably look something like this:

```
<ol>
  <li th:each="v : ${visitors}">
    <span th:text="${v.getSurName()} + ' '+ ${v.getFirstName()}" />
    <ul>
      <li th:text = "${v} + ' '+ ${v.getThemeParkCode()}"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! This seemed to work :)